# how do I optimize computation of Gaussian pdf?

Tags: c++, c, numerical

I am working on a C++ project that often requires the computation of Gaussian pdf given a data point x and an existing Gaussian distribution G.

This is expensive since the exponential function exp is involved. Even if I take log, the log function is costly as well. Any suggestions about how I can do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vectorize it, that is, compute the exponents or logs in parallel using SIMD, you can also use optimized approximating SSE based `exp` and `log` if you don't need extreme accuracy, a simple lib for that can be found [here](http://gruntthepeon.free.fr/ssemath/).

However, when it comes to optimizing, profile first, that way you fix the problem, not what you *think* is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The log pdf isn't expensive, if you use the following shortcut:

Starting with

```
 log_pdf = log (1.0/ (sigma * 2.0 * pi))  - 0.5 * square(x-mean) / ( sigma*sigma );
```

you can see that the part of the term containing the log can be pre-calculated for any particular PDF, as can part of the rest. So for any given values for the standard deviation and the mean:

```
log_k = log (1.0/ (sigma * 2.0 * pi));
half_over_sigma_sq= 0.5 / (sigma*sigma)
```

Then when evaluating for lots of different values of x, you can calculate just

```
log_pdf = log_k - half_over_sigma_sq * square(x-mean);
```

This trick is used all the time in statistical modelling.